# Admob linker command failed

Tags: ios, ios7

So yesterday I integrated admob to my application and evertything worked fine. Today I turned Xcode on and tried to run the applcation and I get Build Failed message. I went to see the error and I got this [image]

I checked my Linker Section in Build Settings and for some reason "ObjC" from Debug and Release was removed so I added it again but I am still getting same error

Code :

```
bannerView = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-8337902504364141/9559897310";
bannerView.rootViewController = self;
[self.view addSubview:bannerView];
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
[bannerView loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
request.testDevices = @[ @"27904e7d64a590b861d78749f3c63c10" ];
```

I checked Libraries in BUild Phases and cleaned project but still getting same error

Comment: you xcodeproj is malformed at libraries section i think, edit that part where you probably missing double quots around your path

Comment: I just fixed this, deleted library search paths and then clicked on libGoogleAdMobAds.a and rechecked Target Membership, thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xcode project looks malformed at libraries section, edit that part where you probably missing double quotes around your path